# Toggle visibility of other fields on form based upon combobox selection - MS Access

Tags: ms-access, combobox, visible

Question...

How can I toggle the visibility of several other fields (checkboxes/textboxes) on form based upon the selection of a combobox item.  The image below shows a listbox but either way, how do use vba code to turn on or off visibility of all the fields in the grey box.  Basically, if the combobox selection is **scheduled** then visible=true. Else visible=false How can I code this???

[image: example]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use combobox AfterUpdate event and probably form Current event as well. So build a procedure that can be called from both events, something like:

```
Sub Form_Current()
SetVisible
End Sub

Sub cbo1_AfterUpdate()
SetVisible
End Sub

Sub SetVisible()
Me.tbx1.Visible = Me.cbo1 = "scheduled"
Me.cbx1.Visible = Me.cbo1 = "scheduled"
End Sub
```

Alternative is to use Conditional Formatting for textboxes and comboboxes (sorry, not applicable to other controls) to Enable/Disable as well as set colors so appear not visible.