# Hide/Unhide some fields based on user selection MS Access

Tags: vba, ms-access

I would ask if i can hide or unhide some fields based on user selections in MS Access

example:
if user choice 'Other' from dropdown menu a text box appears to write down their answer and so on..

### i tried this code after update event but does not work

```
Private Sub NAME_AfterUpdate()
    Select Case Me.NAME
        Case "Other"
            Me.other.Visible = True
          
    End Select
End Sub
```

---

any help?

much appreciated

Comment: Try changing `Select Case Me.NAME` to `NAME.Value`

Comment: Value is default property of data controls and normally not necessary to explicitly reference. However, Name is a reserved and in this case, a property of form so `Me.Name` actually returns name of form or report code is behind. Using `.Value` forces VBA to recognize control named Name. Advise not to use reserved words as object names. tbxName would be better naming convention.

Comment: Review https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65114592/toggle-visibility-of-other-fields-on-form-based-upon-combobox-selection-ms-acc/65115546#65115546. Is your form in Continuous or Datasheet view? If yes, then all records will reflect the same visible/not visible state. Only alternative is to use Conditional Formatting and set enabled/not enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Me.Name` is the name of the form. Thus:

```vb
Private Sub NAME_AfterUpdate()
    Select Case Me!NAME.Value
        Case "Other"
            Me!Other.Visible = True
            ' Read value of "other".
            Me!Name.Value = Me!Other.Value
    End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: hi @Gustav still Other field appear on the other options

Comment: Use of bang (!) does not trigger VBA intellisense. `Me.Name.Value` would and produces same outcome.

Comment: _still Other field appear on the other options_ ... yes, if you don't set _Visible_ to _False_ somewhere else.

Comment: can i use If statement instead of cases?

Comment: Certainly. It is a matter of preference.

Comment: Thank you! and one more question.. can i save the new value of 'other' field In same of NAME column?

Comment: unfortunately, dose not work with me:( any other solution?

Comment: Update.. it's work with me if the type of field is text not list, i mean i want if the user choose "other" option from the list the new item he will add it to be in the list

Comment: The your list doesn't return the expected value.